# google maps js API default map style on v3.48

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Google Maps API version 3.48 changed the default map style.
[image: Compare styles]

Is it possible to revert the old map style using map config or API config?

Comment: Have you tried to change the "Map types" to see if they go back to the style you want? Read more on the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes

Comment: You can specify the version in the script uri

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use Google's documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/overview to create a custom style that mimics the old map style. You go to https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard to your project, then you can go to Other Google Products -> Google Maps -> Map style.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this feature. But in this case I have to make a new map and adjust the colors.
I meant maybe there is an option to specify the old map style without any additional steps - just set the map style. Unfortunately I didn't find any options in googlemaps api.